# How to open Custom Editor with VSCode api

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have an extensions that registers a CustomEditorProvider for a specific file type and I need to create a command that opens a given file with my editor.

If i click on the file from the workspace explorer my editor opens correctly but if I use the showTextDocument api the built-in text editor will open.

```
private openModule(file:vscode.Uri) {
    vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(file).then((doc: vscode.TextDocument) => {
          vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc);
    });
  }
```

On the opened editor in the UI I can "Reopen Editor With..." that prompts me with the selection of the editor. And I if select my custom editor it will be reopened with the correct editor.

[image: Editor provider selection]

How do I force the TextEditor to use the custom one and not the build in?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem, and found my answer here:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98473#issuecomment-634306217

```js
commands.executeCommand("vscode.openWith", uri, MyCustomEditor.viewType);
```